# selenium python: is there some way to send out an e-mail or SMS if a certain event occurred?

Tags: python, selenium, bots, pi

I'm pretty new to coding, however, there's an event in my area which will be bought out very quick so I'm trying to work on a simple bot that tells me when tickets are available. so far I've got the following code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\dzari\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.siteofevent.net/...')

try:
    okbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/button[1]"))
    )
finally:
    okbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/button[1]").click()
# checks if cookies want to be enabled, then clicks agree button

buybutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("uk-text-middle")
# locates the button with text in it that says "Tickets available soon"

if buybutton.text == "Tickets (Folgt)":
    print("Tickets not available")
else:
    print("Tickets are availabe!")
```

Now is there any possibility to somehow send me an e-mail or SMS when tickets are available when I run the script 24/7, e.g., on a pi? and also, how can I restart the `if` loop again and again automatically without having to restart the script? please don't laugh at me i know there's probably a way easier way, however I'm interested in learning to code and this seemed like a fun idea to me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Gmail prevents any login from non-secure browsers like an automated one. I would recommend rather than using Selenium to send an email by navigating to URLs and attempting to sign in. Use SMTPlib instead. Here's how:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import smtplip #pip install smtplib for this to work
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\dzari\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.siteofevent.net/...')

try:
    okbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/button[1]"))
    )
finally:
    okbutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/button[1]").click()
# checks if cookies want to be enabled, then clicks agree button

buybutton = driver.find_element_by_class_name("uk-text-middle")
# locates the button with text in it that says "Tickets available soon"

if buybutton.text == "Tickets (Folgt)":
    print("Tickets not available")
else:
    print("Tickets are available!")
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.ehlo()
    sender = "your email"
    sender_password = "your email password"
    receiver = "who you want to send email to"

    smtp.login(sender, sender_password)
    subject = 'Tickets Were Found!'
    body = "What you want to say about the tickets"
    message = f'Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}'

    smtp.sendmail(sender, receiver, message)
    print("Email sent!")
```

Comment: The smtp.ehlo() helps to prevent gmail from tracing that the email being sent is being automated and the startttls() just starts a new server